# How to count correctly 2 inner levels count?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a structure for a university DB wherein I have three tables: `room`, `students`, `possessions`

```
CREATE TABLE `rooms` (
    `id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
    UNIQUE INDEX `name` (`name`) USING BTREE
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=3
;

CREATE TABLE `students` (
    `id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `ref_room_id` INT(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `student_name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `FK_students_room` (`ref_room_id`) USING BTREE,
    CONSTRAINT `FK_students_room` FOREIGN KEY (`ref_room_id`) REFERENCES `university`.`rooms` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE SET NULL
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=6
;

CREATE TABLE `possessions` (
    `id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `ref_student_id` INT(10) NOT NULL,
    `name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `FK__students` (`ref_student_id`) USING BTREE,
    CONSTRAINT `FK__students` FOREIGN KEY (`ref_student_id`) REFERENCES `university`.`students` (`id`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=4
;

INSERT INTO rooms (name) VALUES ('a'),('b');

INSERT INTO students (`ref_room_id`, `student_name`) VALUES 
(3,1),
(3,2),
(3,3),
(3,4);

INSERT INTO possessions (ref_student_id, name) VALUES 
(7,'a')
(7,'aa'),
(7,'aaa'),
(8,'aaaa'),
(9,'aaaaa'),
(6,'aaaaaa'),
(7,'aaaaaaa');
```

So, in order to present such a table in MySQL, I created the procedure

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `get_data`()
LANGUAGE SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC
CONTAINS SQL
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT ''
BEGIN

SELECT r.id AS room_id, r.name, COUNT(s.id) AS student_num, COUNT(p.id) AS possessions_num
FROM rooms r 
INNER JOIN students s ON s.ref_room_id = r.id
INNER JOIN possessions p ON p.ref_student_id = s.id
GROUP BY r.name;

END
```

but what I get is

[image]

First of all, it misses the room and secondly instead of 4 students it shows 7...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @Strawberry Strawberry what do you want? I provided all the information including creating tables queries, procedure queries, screenshots, what are you missing? You are welcome to reproduce this example

Comment: The sample data producing the outlined result seems to be missing.

Comment: @g_bor added   queries

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko in order for the count of students to show up right you need to do `COUNT(DISTINCT s.id)` but i'm not sure what you mean when you say "it misses the room". could you also include what you want the result set to look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following (and note that my data set may vary slightly from yours...)

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS rooms;
CREATE TABLE `rooms` (
    `id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    );

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS students;
CREATE TABLE `students` (
    `id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `ref_room_id` INT(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `student_name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    );

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS possessions;
CREATE TABLE `possessions` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `ref_student_id` INT NOT NULL,
    `name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`) 
    );

INSERT INTO rooms VALUES (1,'a'),(2,'b');

INSERT INTO students VALUES 
(11,1,1),
(12,1,2),
(13,1,3),
(14,1,4);

INSERT INTO possessions VALUES 
(101,11,'apple'),
(102,11,'banana'),
(103,11,'cherry'),
(104,12,'date'),
(105,15,'elderberry'),
(106,13,'fig'),
(107,14,'huckleberry');

SELECT r.*
     , COUNT(DISTINCT s.id) total_students
     , COUNT(DISTINCT p.id) total_possessions
  FROM rooms r
  JOIN students s
    ON s.ref_room_id = r.id
  JOIN possessions p
    ON p.ref_student_id = s.id
 GROUP
    BY r.id;
    
+----+------+----------------+-------------------+
| id | name | total_students | total_possessions |
+----+------+----------------+-------------------+
|  1 | a    |              4 |                 6 |
+----+------+----------------+-------------------+
```

Or...

```
SELECT r.*
     , COUNT(DISTINCT s.id) total_students
     , COUNT(DISTINCT p.id) total_possessions
  FROM rooms r
  LEFT
  JOIN students s
    ON s.ref_room_id = r.id
  LEFT
  JOIN possessions p
    ON p.ref_student_id = s.id
 GROUP
    BY r.id;
+----+------+----------------+-------------------+
| id | name | total_students | total_possessions |
+----+------+----------------+-------------------+
|  1 | a    |              4 |                 6 |
|  2 | b    |              0 |                 0 |
+----+------+----------------+-------------------+
```